# Show the version of application

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere

I have an application (bank area) build in java ee with jps, on was7.
The core business is in Cobol + db2, interact with java via cics.

When I do deliver in a certain environment, I export an EAR file, I build in ?Jenkins and in Topaz, in LCM, create a package, migrate and promote it into specified environment.

We are asked to display the version of application. I think is the last date of ear file. And I think to get in on date of EAR file, on Git tag, on Jenkins build or date of package in Cobol (JCL?)

I don't any idea to do this. Can you help me please?

PS.1 Please, excuse my English.
PS.2 I can give you more info if necessary, but not more, given that the field is financial-banking...

Comment: Meaning you want to get access to version number stored somewhere in EAR's metafiles from your Java code?

Comment: Yes, this is it. It's important to say that i can't use maven or ant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as an idea. If you run application on WebSphere, you can create Shared Library, add metafiles location to its classpath. Associate shared library with your application, so you can have access to the files as a resources.

Tutorial on how to create and associate shared library: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/create_shared_library_and_associate_it_with_the_application_server_or_application_on_websphere_application_server?lang=en

Comment: Very nice, thanks! But an workaround that works: create a new Java class, and put it the version as final static variable, and then use it as well